# How do I put Google Chrome on my launcher?

Tags: launcher

I recently installed Chrome on Ubuntu, and I can run Chrome via `google-chrome` on the command line.

However, how can I put a Chrome icon on my dock?

Comment: Was able to get a workaround similar to @Saber's answer by following https://askubuntu.com/a/1026532/1369861

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Search for Chrome in the menu and drag it to the dock.

Doing this, you don't need the command line at all.

Comment: I don't see it in the search anymore on Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 12):

Right click on the icon in the dock while it's running and select lock/add to favorites.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to do this, I started Chrome, but it didn't appear on the left band at all. Agmenor's method worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a desktop file (e.g. chrome.desktop) on your Desktop and insert the following content into that file:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome
   Name=Google Chrome
   Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/google-chrome.png
   ```
2. Make it executable by running this command:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/Desktop/chrome.desktop
   ```
3. Add it to the launcher:

   ```
   cp ~/Desktop/chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```

Comment: This works to launch from the desktop, but does not work from the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

open Chrome-> right click on chrome icon from dock -> "Add to favorites". Refer to this Image if you're using ubuntu 17.10[image]