# Adding custom programs to favourites of Ubuntu Dock

Tags: gnome-shell, installed-programs, ubuntu-dock

I want to add a custom program to the favourites of Ubuntu dock, but there is no option for that.

[image]

Translating the text in this image (same as above) only says:

1. All windows
2. Quit

It also doesn't appear in "Show Applications":
[image]

Is there a way for adding the program to both Favourites and Applications menus?

Comment: I want to do the same thing, but it appears this is some war crime.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is fairly easy. First, make a desktop application file that follows the freedesktop.org spec, e.g.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=MyApplication
Comment=My fancy new application
Exec=my_application
Icon=my_application.png
Terminal=false
```

If you want this to be usable by anyone on your system, put it in `/usr/share/applications`. For personal use only, you can put it in `~/.local/share/applications`.   Look in `/usr/share/applications` for other examples.  Add your icon image to the `/usr/share/icons` directory, or I assume the `~/.local/share/icons`, although I have not tried that last location myself.

Then, you can search for the application by name and drag it to the launcher in the usual way!

Comment: This doesnt work anymore on 18.04 :(

Comment: Shervin: I can verify that this still works on 18.04, both using /usr/share/applications or ~/.local/share/applications.  You may need to restart gnome to update the cache.

Comment: One step is missing from the description to make it work: the `.desktop` file needs to be executable, so run e.g. `chmod a+x eclipse.desktop`, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082340/how-to-add-eclipse-to-favorites

Comment: Work properly in 19.10, even did not need any cache cleanup, it instantly showed up in dock search results, plus now I can pin app, thanks!

Comment: For anyone looking to do this from the command line, run `dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`, and you will get a list which starts like `['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop']`. Add your new `.desktop` file to the list and run the **appropriately-modified** command `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps "['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'my-app.desktop']"`. (Be careful since you'll lose your existing favorites if you forget to include them with the `dconf write` command.)

Comment: @BenMares Awesome! this worked for me when I tried to add Zoom to favorite. Thanks! btw just for other people, add the quote marks around the list otherwise it won't work, took me a while to notice haha

Comment: This answer misses that you have to set the executable bit + mark it as trusted: https://askubuntu.com/a/1152748/37881

Comment: I had to do as @PeterM suggested implicitly and search for it from the dock search. I could pin it from there. Just double clicking on it from the applications directory didn't allow it to be pinned.

Comment: @BenMares Thank you, it works. But just found another solution in SO: `gio set </home/path/to/your/whatever.desktop> "metadata::trusted" yes`

Comment: Click on the Configure option and click on “Create Desktop Entry” -> 
https://itsfoss.com/install-pycharm-ubuntu/

Comment: I followed the comment from @BenMares and it did work

Comment: @BenMares You should add that as an answer.