# How to add Eclipse to Favorites?

Tags: 18.04, java, eclipse, ubuntu-dock, dock

I installed the latest version of Eclipse onto Ubuntu 18.04 with the official installer from the Eclipse website, however I can't get it to appear on my favorites bar/dock.

I have tried dragging the executable file to the dock, but it doesn't work.

I can't find it with the "show applications" button. I can only run it by clicking on its executable file.

How can I get Eclipse to appear on the favorites bar/dock?

The .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Eclipse
Terminal=false
Name=Eclipse
Exec=eclipse --profile-directory=/home/myName/eclipse/java-2018-09/eclipse
Type=Application
Icon=eclipse
```

This isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967409/cant-add-custom-desktop-files-to-ubuntu-dock) because the same process doesn't work. Changing the text file to an executable doesn't work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I merged [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967443/725400), OP's answer, below comments and my own experience:

1. Create a file called `Eclipse.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` (e.g. with the command `nano ~/.local/share/applications/Eclipse.desktop`)
2. Add these lines:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=Eclipse
   Terminal=false
   Name=Eclipse
   Exec=/path/to/your/version/eclipse/eclipse
   Type=Application
   Icon=/path/to/your/version/eclipse/icon.xpm
   StartupWMClass=Eclipse
   ```

   Note that 'Exec' should point to your eclipse executable, not the containing folder which is also named 'eclipse' usually. Check if the icon file is present and if necessary adapt its path. Save the file.
3. Make the file executable by running `chmod a+x ~/.local/share/applications/Eclipse.desktop`.
4. Click on 'Show Applications' (the dot logo on the bottom left of the screen) and in the search bar enter 'Eclipse'. It should appear.
5. Right click on the Icon and choose 'Add to favorites'.

There is a lot more you can specify in a .desktop file with further key-value pairs, more info [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).

Comment: Thanks- this helped me as well but a couple of things. You don't need (and you shouldn't use) `sudo` to create the `.desktop` and make it executable. To make .desktop executable by everyone I think the right command is `chmod a+x ~/.local/share/applications/.desktop`.

Comment: Doing as explained above, I got a new icon in the dock for each Eclipse instance I run. Solved by adding StartupWMClass=Eclipse to the .desktop file https://askubuntu.com/a/635839/741521

Comment: @alostale Very nice, I had the same issue and added your solution to the answer.

Comment: it is better to use `program_name.desktop` so if there is another program that you want to add to favorites, you can create another `.desktop` file ex: `second_program.desktop`

Comment: @hosseinhayati How is it better to have multiple files rather than one file with multiple entries? Matter of taste, no?

Comment: I have seen many posts suggesting the use of this procedure and I have never been able to get it to work. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot the situation.

Comment: @hosseinhayati It seems that I was wrong about this and you need to create a file for each new application. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

First the problem with the `.desktop` launcher was fixed by changing the `Exec` line to

```
Exec=/home/myName/eclipse/java-2018-09/eclipse/eclipse
```

Then "added to favorites" following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967409/cant-add-custom-desktop-files-to-ubuntu-dock).