# Add java-program (Eclipse,JabRef,Maple,...) to favorites

Tags: java, ubuntu-dock, dock

If I create a Java-desktop-file in `~/.local/share/applications` I do not have the option "Add to Favorites".

I tried it with JabRef:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=org-jabref-jabrefmain.png
Path=/home/jkalliau/prgm/JabRef
Exec=java -jar JabRef--master--latest.jar %U
Name=JabRef
GenericName=BibTeX Editor
Comment=JabRef is an open source bibliography reference manager.
Keywords=bibtex;biblatex;latex;bibliography
Categories=Office;
StartupWMClass=org-jabref-JabRefMain
MimeType=text/x-bibtex;
```

and with Maple:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Maple 2018
Type=Application
Comment=Maple 2018
Exec=/home/jkalliau/maple2018/bin/xmaple %f
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/jkalliau/maple2018/bin/Maple2018.png
GenericName=Maple
Categories=Applications;Education;Mathematics;
MimeType=application/x-maple-worksheet;
```

[image: NoFavoriteIcon]

If I do the same as in [How to add Eclipse to Favorites?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082340/how-to-add-eclipse-to-favorites) I have the icon twice, once added to favorites and once the opened file.

[image: Icon twice]

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/10407) is also relevant for the case of `JabRef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .desktop-file with the identical `WM_CLASS` of the opened program:

- for JabRef: `org.jabref.gui.JabRefMain.desktop`
- for Maple: `java-lang-Thread.desktop`
- for Eclipse: `eclipse.desktop` (according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59654/241592 )
- for nemo `nemo.desktop` (**not** Files.desktop)
- for academic MatlabR2022a: `MATLAB R2022a - academic use.desktop`
- for Inkscape: `org.inkscape.Inkscape.desktop`

The `WM_CLASS` can be found with the command

```
xprop
```

for more details check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225409/241592 . Use Copy&Paste to avoid spellingmistakes.

---

Or you can also see name in the left upper corner

[image]

or in the Pop-up of the icon in the favourite-list

[image]

As suggest on https://askubuntu.com/a/1120331/676490 after creation of the `.desktop`-file:

- go to activities

[image]

- search the application

[image]

- Click "Add to Favorites"

Comment: Could yo be more specific about the contents of the .desktop file? I mean how should I set the `WM_CLASS` parameter?

Comment: Examples of desktop-files are in the question, the imporant thing is to name the file according to $WM_CLASS.desktop .

Answer (score 0):

For JabRef it is now: `StartupWMClass=org.jabref.gui.MainApplication`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1343087)

Comment: This does not work for me. I am on Ubunut 20.04 LTS with the latest version of JabRef 5.12.