# how to configure Firefox icon for Wayland

Tags: firefox, icons, wayland

I am experimenting with the Wayland option in Ubuntu 20:10 on a Raspberry Pi.

Wayland has a bad impact on Firefox such that its window becomes unreadable. To make Firefox work with Wayland I added the line:

export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1

to the tail end of ~/.bashrc

Having done that I am able to use Firefox if I initiate it from the command line.

If I initiate Firefox by clicking the Firefox icon it behaves as if I had not set MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1

I contemplated messing with the shell script:
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh
whilst it might work, I feel pretty sure it's not the right way to go.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can add in the .desktop file to export it

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082340/how-to-add-eclipse-to-favorites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the export command into ~/.profile.   ~/.bashrc is only run when starting a Bash session, wheras ~/.profile is run with any session (including desktop sessions)